# Set Unique ID to file on Storage

Tags: java, android, file

I am working on an Android Application in which I save a file after some processing to the external storage using the `File` class in Java. I'm also saving some information about the file in a SQL database for some processing in future and so that I can find the file later.

I want to ask that **is there a way to give the file some unique id or property that I can use later to distinguish**. This id or property can be such that it can't be changed by the end-user, and if the file name changes or it does stay the same.

I intend to save this unique ID in the Database to use later to find the file even if the file name changes.

Comment: Can you use the current timestamp?  It will always be unique

Comment: but how will I associate it with the file?

Comment: link you mentioned in Amit's answer is using Java's Files.setAttribute() method, you can combine it with Java's Watch Service(that lets you monitor a `Directory` for changes).

Comment: @RishabhDhawan I'll see to it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some customize thing to achieve what you want. One way is:
You make a top parent directory. Then for every file, you can make a parent directory. Every parent directory must have a unique name. You can use timestamp for that( I can help you more in this if you want). And you can save these parent directory in your database if you needed. Now even if user change file name directory will be the same. And since every directory has just one file, you can use File.listFiles() method to get that one file.

Comment: okay, I didn't get this part - "And you can save these parent directory in your database if you needed." Am I supposed to store the files in the database?

Comment: No, each file parent directory name. Do you want to save anything else in the database? What is the use of the database?

Comment: what if the user changed directory name itself or moved file from one directory to other...

Comment: Then it should be mentioned in the question that the user can change the directory name too along with the file name.

Comment: isn't it too obvious @amit

Comment: No. According to your question, no. Can you explain, what you want to do? According to your question, you want that you should be able to track file even if the file name changed. If there is anything else, please explain it.

Comment: I want to achieve what this tutorial promises but it is not working for me.  https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2016/10/set-unique-identifier-to-file-in-java.html